# How to run a child process, and act on it with the parent in C?

Tags: c, debian, fork, exec

I'm currently trying to run an Internet browser (Firefox) as a child process in a C program and perform actions on it. At first I'd like to get child's `pid` and kill it with parent.

After some researches I've chosen to use `Fork`/`exec` to create a child process.
But when I execute my code, the two programs doesn't run simultaneously.
After I opened my browser, I can't do anything before closing it.

My code looks like that

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{

    //version fork
    pid_t pid;
    char *parmList[] = {"firefox", "google.com", NULL};
    int a;
    printf("test001");
    if ((pid = fork()) == -1)
      perror("fork failed");

     if (pid == 0) {
        printf("test002");
        a = execvp("/usr/bin/firefox", parmList);
        printf("test003");
     }
     else {
       waitpid(pid, 0, 0);
       printf("test004");
     }
  return 0;
}
```

For now I got navigator running with some errors due to Firefox.
And I get this kind of output :

```
root@debian:/home/user/Documents/Projet/git_sources/ProjetSIDA# ./a.out

(process:3858): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
console.error: 
  [CustomizableUI]
  Custom widget with id loop-button does not return a valid node
console.error: 
  [CustomizableUI]
  Custom widget with id loop-button does not return a valid node
```

And this last line when I close iceweasel:

> test001test004root@debian:/home/user/Documents/Projet/git_sources/ProjetSIDA#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not able to do anything with your command prompt when your browser is on is because this line of code.

```
waitpid(pid, 0, 0);
```

If you comment it out, you can open the browser and get your command prompt back to accept input again.

The reason is your are asking your main process(`a.out` in your case) to wait for the browser process to change its state with `waitpid(pid, 0, 0);`.